# referencing objects by name as attributes

Tags: python, oop, attributes, coding-style

Are there good reasons to/not to store a list of objects as "sub attributes"?  In the example below, I store several animal objects in a Zoo under the `animals` attribute, *e.g.* `zoo.animals.<animal object referenced by name>`.  This syntax makes it easier to access the attributes of the stored animals and I'm wondering if there are downsides of this construction I haven't yet considered:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, num_legs, furry):
        self.name = name
        self.num_legs = num_legs
        self.furry = furry

class ObjAsAttributes(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for k,v in kwargs.items():
            setattr(self, k, v)

class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self, animals):
        self.name = 'my zoo'
        self.hours = '8am-6pm'
        animals = {animal.name:animal for animal in animals}
        self.animals = ObjAsAttributes(**animals)




animal_list = [Animal(name='bird', num_legs=2, furry=False),
               Animal(name='giraffe', num_legs=4, furry=True),
               Animal(name='octopus', num_legs=8, furry=False)]

zoo = Zoo(animal_list)
zoo.animals.bird.num_legs
# returns 2
```

Comment: This is actually part of the standard at my workplace, I can't tell you for sure if it's good or bad practice, but what I can say is that if you plan on adding more "sub-attributes" , for example, you have a specific type of bird and you want to store its talon size, that would be abstracted away under num_legs and extended on it. So you would have `zoo.animals.bird.num_legs.talon_size` , this can get quite messy, which I do see plenty of, however if you don't expect to add onto it anytime soon I've never seen anything wrong with it.

Comment: It is just unnecessary and doesnt help much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In my opinion, doing so will make your code hard to debug, inflexible and unreadable. This is a bad idea.** What happens if, for example:

1. You have a animal name that contains a space? Such as "electric eel"?
2. If you want to iterate over animals, you will have to do

   ```
   for name in vars(obj):
       print(getattr(obj, name))
   ```

   - In essence, you may have to re-implement all standard container functions, such as insert, add, delete, filter, etc., or use very non-intuitive syntax.
3. How will you merge or filter this with another zoo? Also there is no way to sort these values if you need to do so.

*Attributes are meant to "hold data" or "describe features" of a modeled object. You should use them only for that purpose.*

---

**As you are mainly looking for fast and easy access, use a `dict` or `OrderedDict`**:

```
class Animal(object):
    def __init__(self, name, num_legs, furry):
        self.name = name
        self.num_legs = num_legs
        self.furry = furry

class Zoo(object):
    def __init__(self, animals):
        self.name = 'my zoo'
        self.hours = '8am-6pm'
        self.animals = {animal.name:animal for animal in animals}

animal_list = [Animal(name='bird', num_legs=2, furry=False),
               Animal(name='giraffe', num_legs=4, furry=True),
               Animal(name='octopus', num_legs=8, furry=False)]

zoo = Zoo(animal_list)
zoo.animals['bird'].num_legs
# returns 2
```